# Automatic Printing of a .pdf using javascript - problems in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, printing

I am not a programmer at all, but I am having major issues with a website I need to use for my work.

Basically, it is a site that we use for check-in and badge printing at a conference. The person scans their barcode and their badge prints automatically. The automatic printing is done by javascript and the file is a .pdf. The person can also type in their badge id/number if they don't  have their barcode and it will also print the badge.

However, it doesn't work and all I get is this weird box with a thing that looks like a cell phone and the .pdf doesn't print. I can't post an image, you can view the image at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-WvmMoRV1V2cmVBMWhJSWhWaVE/edit?usp=sharing.

Below is the coding I could find on the site.

```
    function callPDF() {

        var t = setTimeout("printPDF()", 4000);
    }

    function printPDF() {

        var x = document.getElementById("pdfDocument");
         x.focus(); 
         //Straight to printer
         x.printAll();  
        //Opend print dialog
         //x.print();

        document.getElementById('dnn_ctr16574_Clients_Custom_ctl00_tb_ID').focus();
      }
```

The programmer I am working with is running IE 11 on windows 8 and Adobe Reader XI and he can get it to print with no issues. I am running IE 11 on Windows 7 and Adobe Reader XI and I can't get it to work AT ALL! I was able to get it to print using IE 8 and Adobe Reader XI, but it's a pain to have to roll back to IE 8 (and I tried rolling back to IE 9 and 10 and couldn't print, I think it is my computer or something that is the problem).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try [disabling protected mode](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/09/11/turn-enhanced-protected-mode-internet-explorer-10-newer/).

Comment: It looks like the path is wrong. Open the f12 tools, go to the networking tab. Press the green button. Reload the page. See if there is a 404 to the PDF and see what the path or url is to the PDF.